# Determine type of controller - MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I need to find out the type of controller which is currently topmost in application.

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.Subviews.Last().GetType()
```

returns UIView. I'm aware that when you use `AddSubview()` method, you pass View, not the Controller.
Objective-C has IsKindOfClass method, but what I really try to do is when user presses home button, if movieplayer controller is on top, I want to  dismiss it. The only place for me to do it is `OnResignActivation()` method in app's delegate as far as I know.

Thank you in advance,

Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by the "topmost"? If you are talking about modally shown controllers, you should really know what's on top because you are presenting the controllers. :-)

So you could keep a reference to the controller you are currently presenting (in AppDelegate e.g.). You will then know what you are showing.

You can also check the presenting view controllers `ModalViewController` property. It will have a reference to the controller that is currently presented modally (or NULL, if none).
You can then check `if(oMyController.ModalViewController is MPMoviePlayerController) { /* do something, like dismissal */}`.

But to dismiss a modally presented controller you do not even have to know what it is. Just call the presenting controller's `DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(bool)` method, and whatever has been shown modally will be gone.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I, however, didn't want to keep references to all of my controllers that can present movie players modally in app delegate and check which one is currently visible and whether it had presented movie player. I tried to do it in a more elegant manner. But definitely, a very good reply.